# Issue search and excel export for JIRA, outside JIRA

Tags: excel, jira

I'm looking to download a list of issues from our JIRA issue list, to process further in VBA and generate a report from the issue list. I want this process to be automated from start to end so e.g. I run a java or VB or C# program, which does a search and download from JIRA (somehow) then runs a VBA program to extract and format the issues into a report. Is there anyway this can be done? I'm using JIRA 3.13.

I've looked at the JIRA and Atlassian plugins but don't quite understand how they work. Aren't plugins meant to be deployed into the JIRA instance. I don't see how plugins can achieve what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to use the JIRA SOAP web service via a SOAP client in your program. This can call the getIssuesFromFilter method to return the results of a filter. Then generate the csv file for Excel to import or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

**[Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel) was exactly designed for these type of usage.**

You can export your issues to a worksheet, then instruct the XLS template to process them using the Excel tools, like [formulas and functions](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/formulas), [charts](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/charts), [pivot tables](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/pivot-tables) and [pivot charts](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/pivot-charts), to produce full blown reports. It is fully automatic and the report can be generated by a single click.

If you look for automation, like generating and emailing the report periodically, or generating and saving the report when an issue event occurs, the companion add-on [Excel Automation Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.excelautomation) is super useful.

Here is a sample report to give you an idea about the capabilities:

[image]